# DMA completion interrupt not working for slave STM32 SPI

Tags: spi, stm32, dma

I am using stm32f103 to transmit some data over SPI while stm32 acts as slave. I need to use DMA for sending data to the SPI but the corresponding interrupt handler is never called.

The initialization code comes in the following:

```
DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;
/* DMA configuration */
DMA_DeInit(SPI_SLAVE_DMA);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t) SPI_SLAVE_DR_Adress;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t) SPI_Buffer;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = SPI_BufferSize;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
DMA_Init(SPI_SLAVE_DMA, &DMA_InitStructure);
/* Enable DMA Transfer Complete interrupt */
DMA_ITConfig(SPI_SLAVE_DMA, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
/* Enable DMA */
DMA_Cmd(SPI_SLAVE_DMA, ENABLE);

/* SPI_SLAVE configuration */
SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_1Line_Tx;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Slave;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Hard;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_2;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
SPI_Init(SPI_SLAVE, &SPI_InitStructure);

/* Enable SPI_SLAVE Tx request */
SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPI_SLAVE, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
/* Enable SPI_SLAVE */
SPI_Cmd(SPI_SLAVE, ENABLE);
```

When I use SPI interrupt handler, my system works. But using the code written above, interrupt handler of SPI_SLAVE_DMA channel is never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. In [reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf) of STM32f103xx there is a table (No. 78) clarifying that which DMA channel can be used for which peripheral. According to that table, I had to use DMA1 channel3, while I was using channel6 instead.